# Converting multiple text files to a csv to create a labelled dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, file-handling

I have text files in multiple folders(folder names are the names of categories/labels). I want to generate  a csv file(dataset) that also has a column as the label(folder name) of that category of text.

```
import csv
import os

folder = os.path.dirname("/home/jaideep/Desktop/folder/ML DS/Csv/Datasets/")
folder_list = os.listdir(folder)

with open("/home/jaideep/Desktop/folder/ML DS/Csv/data.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['Label', 'Email','Message'])
    for f in folder_list:
        file_list = os.listdir(folder+"/"+f+"/")
        print(file_list)
        for file in file_list:
            with open(file, "r")  as infile:
                contents = infile.read()
                outfile.write(f+',')
                outfile.write(contents)
```

But I'm getting

```
File "/home/jaideep/Desktop/folder/ML DS/Csv/Main.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open(file, "r")  as infile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.txt'
```

I know there are similar questions previously asked, but I couldn't file solution to my issue. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` only lists the filenames of a directory, so you need to reconstruct the path.

You may want to check out `glob` for that matter.

This version should solve your issue.

```
import csv
import os

folder = os.path.dirname("/home/jaideep/Desktop/folder/ML DS/Csv/Datasets/")
folder_list = os.listdir(folder)

with open("/home/jaideep/Desktop/folder/ML DS/Csv/data.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(['Label', 'Email','Message'])
    for f in folder_list:
        file_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(folder, f))
        print(file_list)
        for file in file_list:
            with open(os.path.join(folder, f, file), "r")  as infile:
                contents = infile.read()
                outfile.write(f+',')
                outfile.write(contents)
```